# How to set the boarder/margin to all the content on a page in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a page something similar to this one. I want all the content on this page has margins to the most left side and most right side of the page. What should I put into my code?

[image: The paragraph "Help us.....accordingly" has margin to the most left side and most right side of the page]

The code I have now will make the paragraph fit the width of the webpage which I don't like.

[image: My current page]

Comment: You should create a global container for your content, give it a `max-width` and then set its margins to `0 auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a global container for your content, give it a `max-width` and then set its margins to `0 auto`.

You can try looking at the following snippet in full screen; since I'm telling the `.container` class to have a maximum width of `600px`, the left and right margins will automatically distribute the available space that remains to center the content with `margin: 0 auto`

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem quo a repellat consequuntur sapiente distinctio, voluptate hic facilis veritatis impedit sed sunt delectus blanditiis soluta tempore cupiditate fugiat ut excepturi accusantium harum neque
    eius ex! Ipsum, ratione. Natus, veritatis et vitae, sint explicabo cum iusto, provident laudantium culpa consectetur corrupti exercitationem deserunt hic error quibusdam. Similique officia tenetur suscipit voluptatum hic maiores, eum possimus, aspernatur
    fugit ad porro sequi? Assumenda impedit maiores, consectetur beatae expedita in libero! Officia modi officiis harum ratione consectetur, doloribus molestiae, quam animi possimus similique, recusandae a deserunt tenetur aliquam fuga! Modi reprehenderit
    placeat natus a laborum nihil voluptatum facere, alias aliquid dolor velit minus libero, corrupti fuga tenetur sapiente est, quo explicabo consequatur? Repellat, adipisci ipsa, saepe praesentium odio, consequatur quia temporibus nemo tempora illo
    suscipit beatae. Voluptates corporis, ipsa officiis, ex accusamus assumenda dolor debitis perferendis voluptas quo quisquam tenetur molestias pariatur doloremque dolorem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem quo a repellat consequuntur sapiente distinctio, voluptate hic facilis veritatis impedit sed sunt delectus blanditiis soluta tempore cupiditate fugiat ut excepturi accusantium harum neque
    eius ex! Ipsum, ratione. Natus, veritatis et vitae, sint explicabo cum iusto, provident laudantium culpa consectetur corrupti exercitationem deserunt hic error quibusdam. Similique officia tenetur suscipit voluptatum hic maiores, eum possimus, aspernatur
    fugit ad porro sequi? Assumenda impedit maiores, consectetur beatae expedita in libero! Officia modi officiis harum ratione consectetur, doloribus molestiae, quam animi possimus similique, recusandae a deserunt tenetur aliquam fuga! Modi reprehenderit
    placeat natus a laborum nihil voluptatum facere, alias aliquid dolor velit minus libero, corrupti fuga tenetur sapiente est, quo explicabo consequatur? Repellat, adipisci ipsa, saepe praesentium odio, consequatur quia temporibus nemo tempora illo
    suscipit beatae. Voluptates corporis, ipsa officiis, ex accusamus assumenda dolor debitis perferendis voluptas quo quisquam tenetur molestias pariatur doloremque dolorem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem quo a repellat consequuntur sapiente distinctio, voluptate hic facilis veritatis impedit sed sunt delectus blanditiis soluta tempore cupiditate fugiat ut excepturi accusantium harum neque
    eius ex! Ipsum, ratione. Natus, veritatis et vitae, sint explicabo cum iusto, provident laudantium culpa consectetur corrupti exercitationem deserunt hic error quibusdam. Similique officia tenetur suscipit voluptatum hic maiores, eum possimus, aspernatur
    fugit ad porro sequi? Assumenda impedit maiores, consectetur beatae expedita in libero! Officia modi officiis harum ratione consectetur, doloribus molestiae, quam animi possimus similique, recusandae a deserunt tenetur aliquam fuga! Modi reprehenderit
    placeat natus a laborum nihil voluptatum facere, alias aliquid dolor velit minus libero, corrupti fuga tenetur sapiente est, quo explicabo consequatur? Repellat, adipisci ipsa, saepe praesentium odio, consequatur quia temporibus nemo tempora illo
    suscipit beatae. Voluptates corporis, ipsa officiis, ex accusamus assumenda dolor debitis perferendis voluptas quo quisquam tenetur molestias pariatur doloremque dolorem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem quo a repellat consequuntur sapiente distinctio, voluptate hic facilis veritatis impedit sed sunt delectus blanditiis soluta tempore cupiditate fugiat ut excepturi accusantium harum neque
    eius ex! Ipsum, ratione. Natus, veritatis et vitae, sint explicabo cum iusto, provident laudantium culpa consectetur corrupti exercitationem deserunt hic error quibusdam. Similique officia tenetur suscipit voluptatum hic maiores, eum possimus, aspernatur
    fugit ad porro sequi? Assumenda impedit maiores, consectetur beatae expedita in libero! Officia modi officiis harum ratione consectetur, doloribus molestiae, quam animi possimus similique, recusandae a deserunt tenetur aliquam fuga! Modi reprehenderit
    placeat natus a laborum nihil voluptatum facere, alias aliquid dolor velit minus libero, corrupti fuga tenetur sapiente est, quo explicabo consequatur? Repellat, adipisci ipsa, saepe praesentium odio, consequatur quia temporibus nemo tempora illo
    suscipit beatae. Voluptates corporis, ipsa officiis, ex accusamus assumenda dolor debitis perferendis voluptas quo quisquam tenetur molestias pariatur doloremque dolorem.
  </p>
</div>
```